# What am I doing wrong here? Maple: LinearSolve, conditionnumber, emf, etc.

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, maple

```
rule := proc (i, j) options operator, arrow; evalf(1/(i+2*j-1)) end proc
A := Matrix(5, rule);
x := Vector(5, 1);
b := A . x;
sol := LinearSolve(A,b);
be := Norm(A, sol-b, infinity);
fe := Norm(x-sol, infinity);

ConditionNumber(A);

emf := fe*Norm(b . infinity)/(Norm(x . infinity)*be);
```

This is just not working out for me.  I do not know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Firstly, I don't see the command that imports the LinearAlgebra package:
$$\text{}$$
with(LinearAlgebra):

Comment: Secondly, that's not the correct syntax for the Norm function. Check the online help. I haven't checked anything further.

Comment: Certainly you must have mixed up some commas and dots, `be := Norm(A . sol - b, infinity);` `Norm(b, infinity)` and `Norm(x, infinity)`.

Answer (score 0):

The question has been answered in the comments the post (why they were not posted as answers is not for me to know), but to summarize:

You need to be more careful about , and .  in your calls to Norm.

Your corrected code should read:

```
with(LinearAlgebra):
rule := (i, j)->evalf(1/(i+2*j-1));
A := Matrix(5, rule);
x := Vector(5, 1);
b := A . x;
sol := LinearSolve(A, b);

be := Norm((A.sol)-b, infinity);
fe := Norm(x-sol, infinity);
ConditionNumber(A);
emf := fe*Norm(b, infinity)/(Norm(x, infinity)*be);
```